# Why doesn't this simple jQuery work

Tags: javascript, jquery, equation

```
$(function() {

    var div  = $('div');

    $('input').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            div.html(div.text() += 49);    
        } else {
            div.html(div.text() -= 49);      
        }
    });

});
```

This is crazy, for some reason the `+=` and `-=` flag up bad assignment, why so?

By the way, I'm not using this code for anything, I know its bad, I'm just testing the `+=`

Example! http://jsfiddle.net/dD73X/

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add values?

Comment: @JaredFarrish http://jsfiddle.net/dD73X/

Comment: @JaredFarrish That's not really the answer though is it. That's just a  nasty work-around.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, or what you mean by "nasty workaround"? (Note, it also should have used `parseInt()` as the answers are suggesting.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish How can you not understand what I was trying to do, check out the top answer, maybe that will help.

Comment: Except for the missing `parseInt()`, that *is* what that fiddle did... If you're adding the fields, *add* the fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot assign something to a temporary result. Use `+` and `-` instead. Also, there would be no need to assign with the compound operators because `div.html(...)` does exactly that: it replaces the text of the div with the result of the addition/subtraction.

**Update:** It seems that you also want to do integer addition (instead of string concatenation). You 'd need to include `parseInt` as well for that, making the code:

```
 $('input').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        div.html(parseInt(div.text()) + 49);
    } else {
        div.html(parseInt(div.text()) - 49);
    }
});
```

Comment: In other words, div.text() isn't an lvalue - you're trying to assign to it, and you can't.

Comment: Instead of parseInt, I just did `div.text()*1 + 49`.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: I thought it better to skip the `lvalue`/`rvalue` terminology here. That's a nice trick with `*` though!

Comment: Or use unary plus: `+div.text() + 49` which is more comprehensible imo (instead of `*1` at least).

Comment: @FelixKling: That's pretty as well. On the other hand all of this starts to slide into the category of "things that look smart but you really really should avoid doing in your professional work". :/

Comment: @FelixKling I was actually using `+div.text()` but I made the error of still doing `+=`

Comment: Ummmm... using `text() * 1` may seem a nice trick but it's semantically incorrect and confusing due to Javascript difference between `+` and `*` when applied to strings. Please use parseInt() for conversions, future readers of your code will appreciate that ;-).

Answer (score 0):

```
 div.html(parseInt(div.text(), 10) += 49);
```

Comment: Always add `, 10)` to `parseInt`, otherwise `parseInt("080") === 0`.

Comment: @pimvdb , yeah good point to mention , althogh I dont think he needs it....( he didnt even noticeed about the parseInt....)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, which does the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/dD73X/2/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').change(function() {
        var t = parseInt($('div').text(), 10);
        if ($('input').attr('checked')) {
            $('div').text(t += 49);
        }else{
            $('div').text(t -= 49);
        }
    });
});
```